# Which desktop environment does Maru OS use?

Tags: desktop-environment, maru-os

[Maru OS](http://maruos.com/#/) has merged Android and GNU userlands into a single OS. It looks like it's based on Android Lollipop and Debian. Which desktop environment does it use for its desktop mode?

Comment: It has an "Applications" Menu/Button on the top left, and a bottom dock in the screenshots? XFCE perhaps?

Comment: @AlexStragies I agree that this seems likely. It also makes sense considering it's running on limited hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I just got an official answer in an email from the main Maru OS developer.

> Maru runs XFCE at the moment. There's some work needed to let users choose an alternate DE.

Comment: +1 for your effort. [The project FAQ](https://github.com/maruos/maruos/wiki/FAQ) on GitHub [has since](https://github.com/maruos/maruos/wiki/FAQ/_compare/181a85fbb68e2cddd18e008e56f04afada393eee...bbd22b4f64a03770f0e3af33b22205d906297843) included "What is Maru Desktop based on?" and the answer is "Debian 8 Jessie and Xfce".